# SQL - foreach column make slug form different column

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreach, slug

I am new with writing complex `SQL` queries. I am on `Postgres 14` and I I am executing migration file which has following concept.

I want to add string field with name slug which will be required like:

```
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE tag ADD COLUMN slug VARCHAR NOT NULL');
```

As the table is already populated and my new column needs to be **required**

I want to:
*Create Null-able column, then update `slug` table column with valid not null values and finally **ALTER** column to set NOT NULL constraint!*

My table (with potential slug column):

```
| id | name             | type | slug             |
|----|------------------|------|------------------|
|  1 | LARPs: The Series|      | larps-the-series |     
|----|------------------|------|------------------|
|  2 | #MyHaliburton.   |      | my-haliburton    |
```

**Catch:**

Added column called “slug” is is a 'slugified' version of the **name** (*all lower case, removed punctuation, spaces replaces with dashes*).

I started with:

```
UPDATE `tag` SET slug = lower(name),
slug = replace(slug, ':', '-'),
slug = replace(slug, '#'', ''),
...
```

Is this right way to cover all the cases? And yet, how to do it for all fields? Should I use `FOR EACH`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do your `slug` generation in one command, combining a call to `LOWER` with two calls to `REGEXP_REPLACE`, one of which strips leading and trailing non-alphabetic characters, and the other which replaces non-alphabetic characters internal to the string with a `-` and also inserts a `-` when a lower-case character is followed by an upper case character:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tag ADD COLUMN slug VARCHAR;

UPDATE tag
SET slug = LOWER(
  REGEXP_REPLACE(
    REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '^[^A-Za-z]+|[^A-Za-z]+$', '', 'g'),
    '[^A-Za-z]+|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', '-', 'g')
  )
;

ALTER TABLE tag ALTER COLUMN slug SET NOT NULL;
```

Output (for your sample input):

```
id  name                    type    slug
1   LARPs: The Series               larps-the-series
2   #MyHaliburton.                  my-haliburton
```

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/idpQr58a4Nfk6pNowi9aTN/1)

Comment: Wow! This did the job. Thanks a lot! @Nick

Comment: @FilipStojavonic No worries - I'm glad I could help. I think the regex replaces should cover most of your requirements, but if not, they should be reasonably easy to modify.